# Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Prove that $\chi(G) \ge \frac{n}{\alpha(G)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, coloring

$\chi$ is the chromatic number of $G$, and $\alpha$ is the independence number of $G$.

I know that if $G$ has a proper coloring, then the set of vertices with a particular color is an independent set.

$V_i = \{v \in V : v$ is colored with color $i\}$

I think I need to move forward by explaining why $|V_i|$ can't be greater than $\alpha(G)$.

How can I move forward with these base ideas? Any hints?

> Proof.
>   Let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices.
>   If G has a proper coloring, then the vertices of each particular color form an independent set.
>   Let $V_i = \{v \in V : v$ is colored with color $i\}$. 
>   The largest number of vertices that can form an independent set in $G$ is denoted by $\alpha(G)$. 
>   We know that $|V_i| \le \alpha(G)$ because $V_i$ can't be a larger independent set than the largest independent set. 
>   ...
>   Therefore  $\chi(G) \ge \frac{n}{\alpha(G)}$.

Comment: You know that $V_i$ is an independent set? And you're stuck on trying to figure out why $|V_i|\le\alpha$? What is the definition of $\alpha(G)$ again? Something about independent sets, isn't it? (I think that's why it's called the independence number?)

Comment: Perhaps I'm having trouble writing the formal part of it because I'm lost in the notation.

Comment: What is your definition of $\alpha(G)$?

Comment: $\alpha(G)$ is the largest number of vertices that form an independent set in $G$.

Comment: Good. Can you prove that, if $S$ is an independent set of vertices in $G,$ then $|S|\le\alpha(G)$?

Comment: And you know that $|V_i$ is an independent set of vertices? So why are you having trouble with "why $|V_i|$ can't be greater than $\alpha(G)$"?

Comment: I've edited my main post, but I'm not sure how to connect that information with my conclusion. Am I missing another very obvious connection..? How do I tie this in with $\frac{n}{\alpha(G)}$?

Comment: You want to show that $n\le\chi(G)\alpha(G).$ Let's see. If you've got vertices of $\chi$ different colors, and at most $\alpha$ vertices of each color, then what's the largest number of vertices you can have?

Comment: Isn't that just $\chi * \alpha$?

Comment: Yes. Any further questions?

Comment: I would say I'm following about halfway but I am not seeing the overall picture. I know you've explained it in pieces in the comments, but could you post an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a proper coloring of $G$ with $\chi(G)=k$ colors. Let $V_i$ be the set of all vertices of color $i,$ for $i=1,2,\dots,k.$ Since $V_i$ is an independent set of vertices (because the coloring is proper), we have $|V_i|\le\alpha(G)$ for each $i.$ It follows that
$$n=|V|=\left|\bigcup_{i=1}^kV_i\right|=\sum_{i=1}^k|V_i|\le\sum_{i=1}^k\alpha(G)=k\alpha(G)=\chi(G)\alpha(G).$$
Dividing the inequality $n\le\chi(G)\alpha(G)$ by $\alpha(G),$ we get
$$\frac n{\alpha(G)}\le\chi(G).$$